# Медленно работает скролл в WinApi

Tags: winapi, c++

Точнее медленно перерисовывает, при прокрутке постоянно видно "моргание". 
И медленнее перерисовывается при горизонтальной прокрутке.
Может я что то делаю не так? Полюзуюсь CodeBlocs.

```
#include <windows.h>  
LRESULT CALLBACK DCDemoWndProc(HWND,UINT,UINT,LONG);  
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

{
    HWND hWnd;  
    WNDCLASS WndClass;  
    MSG Msg;  
    char szClassName[]="DCDemo";  
    //reg class  
    WndClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;  
    WndClass.lpfnWndProc=DCDemoWndProc;  
    WndClass.cbClsExtra=0;  
    WndClass.cbWndExtra=0;  
    WndClass.hInstance=hInstance;  
    WndClass.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_ASTERISK);  
    WndClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);  
    WndClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);    
    WndClass.lpszMenuName="MyMenu";  
    WndClass.lpszClassName=szClassName;  
    if (!RegisterClass(&WndClass))  
        {  
            MessageBox(NULL,"Cannot register class","Error",MB_OK);  
            return 0;  
        }  
    hWnd=CreateWindow(szClassName,"Picture",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_HSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,  
                      NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);  
    if(!hWnd)  
        {  
            MessageBox(NULL,"Cannot create windoe:(","Error",MB_OK);  
            return 0;  
        }  
    ShowWindow(hWnd,nCmdShow);  
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);  
    while(GetMessage(&Msg,NULL,0,0))  
    {  
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);    
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);  
    }  
return Msg.wParam;  
}  
LRESULT CALLBACK DCDemoWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message,UINT wParam,LONG lParam )  
{  
    HDC hDC,hCompatibleDC;  
    PAINTSTRUCT PaintStruct;  
    static HANDLE hBitmap;  
    HANDLE hOldBitmap;  
    RECT Rect;  
    BITMAP Bitmap;  
    static int nHorizDifference=0,nVertDifference=0;  
    static int nHorizPosition=0,nVertPosition=0;  
    switch(Message)  
{  
    case WM_CREATE:  
            hBitmap=LoadImage(NULL, "c:\\X.BMP", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,   LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            return 0;  
    case WM_PAINT:  
            hDC=BeginPaint(hWnd,&PaintStruct);  
            GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);  
            hCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);  
            hOldBitmap=SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, hBitmap);  
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &Rect);  
            BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, Rect.right, Rect.bottom,hCompatibleDC,   nHorizPosition,nVertPosition,  
                       SRCCOPY);  
            if((nHorizDifference=(Bitmap.bmWidth-Rect.right))>0)  
                    SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_HORZ, 0, nHorizDifference, TRUE);  
            else  
                    SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_HORZ, 0, 0, TRUE);  
            if((nVertDifference=(Bitmap.bmHeight-Rect.bottom))>0)  
                    SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_VERT, 0,nVertDifference, TRUE);  
            else  
                    SetScrollRange(hWnd, SB_VERT, 0,0,TRUE);

            SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, hOldBitmap);  
            DeleteDC(hCompatibleDC);  
            EndPaint(hWnd,&PaintStruct);
            return 0;
    case WM_VSCROLL:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                {
                    case SB_LINEDOWN:
                            if (nVertPosition<nVertDifference)
                            nVertPosition++;
                    break;
                    case SB_LINEUP:
                            if(nVertPosition>0)
                            nVertPosition--;
                    break;
                    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                            nVertPosition=HIWORD(wParam);
                    break;
                }
            SetScrollPos(hWnd,SB_VERT,nVertPosition,TRUE);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            return 0;
    case WM_HSCROLL:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case SB_LINEDOWN:
                        if(nHorizPosition<nHorizDifference)
                            nHorizPosition++;
                break;
                case SB_LINEUP:
                        if(nHorizPosition>0)
                            nHorizPosition--;
                break;
                case SB_THUMBTRACK:
                        nHorizPosition=(HIWORD(wParam));
                break;
            }
        SetScrollPos(hWnd,SB_HORZ,nHorizPosition,TRUE);
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL,TRUE);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
}
return DefWindowProc(hWnd,Message,wParam,lParam);
```

}

Comment: @Влад Малахин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мерцание происходит из-за очистки фона при отрисовке - `DefWindowProc` заливает все окно цветом фона. Если обрабатывать вручную событие `WM_ERASEBKGND`, мерцания не будет.
Просто добавьте в `DCDemoWndProc`

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
return 0;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло. Только учусь, и в книге о данном сообщении не было написано.